# Ubuntu does not seem to be auto-mounting NTFS drives despite the settings claiming so. How can I resolve this?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, nautilus, ntfs

I have a 1TB NTFS hard drive that I'd like Ubuntu to mount on startup. The settings here seem to suggest it should.

[image: mount settings]

But when I try to access it from another program, it claims that it's not accessible.

[image: can't access drive]

In Nautilus, you can see it's unmounted and (unseen here) it prompts me to mount it by clicking.

[image: unmounted]

When I click on it, it mounts it (as you can see since I can now eject it).

[image: mounted]

And after doing this, it's accessible in the other program.

[image: can access drive]

Comment: You didn't create a directory to mount.

Comment: Automount point seems located to /mnt/... while this directory is probably missing.

Comment: Why don't you black out more of the information that we might need to help you with your problem? This is not top secret information.

Comment: The blacked out information was the hard driver model name (probably unnecessary, yes)  and then lastly the path, which includes my username containing my real name and then hard drive serial number. Thanks for the sarcasm in any case. FWIW, the blacked out path is just "[username]/[hard drive GUID]".

Comment: Its his choice to keep the username hidden. Respect it. What is the other program you write about?

Comment: The blackouts are confusing and making the image hard (for me) to read.  As far as auto-mounting, I would suggest using **fstab** for that.  You can most likely take the blacked out information and place it into fstab, of course using the [standard fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) entry format.

Comment: if you want it always there; why not add it to /etc/fstab (file system table).